# Using Boolean algebra, how do I convert the SOP expression listed below into A ⊕ B ⊕ C ⊕ D?

Tags: logic, computer-science, boolean-algebra

SOP expression:

A'B'C'D + A'B'CD' + A'BC'D' + A'BCD + AB'C'D' + AB'CD + ABC'D + ABCD'

Desired expression:

A ⊕ B ⊕ C ⊕ D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the [distributive law](http://www.ee.surrey.ac.uk/Projects/Labview/boolalgebra/#distributivelaw) to factor out $A$ and $A'$:

$$A'(B'C'D + B'CD' + BCD + BC'D') +
  A(B'C'D' + B'CD + BC'D + BCD')$$

Within the parentheses, factor out $B$ and $B'$:

$$A'(B'(C'D + CD') + B(CD + C'D')) +
  A(B'(C'D' + CD) + B(C'D + CD'))$$

Rewrite $(C'D+CD')$ by $(C \oplus D)$ and $(C'D'+CD)$ by $(C \oplus D)'$:

$$A'(B'(C \oplus D) + B(C \oplus D)') +
  A(B'(C \oplus D)' + B(C \oplus D))$$

In a similar manner:

$$A'(B \oplus (C \oplus D)) +
  A(B \oplus (C \oplus D))'$$

and:

$$A \oplus (B \oplus (C \oplus D))$$

Exclusive or is [associative](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/293793/prove-xor-is-commutative-and-associative). Therefore, parentheses can be omitted:

$$A \oplus B \oplus C \oplus D$$